# Options not being displayed in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to display the option for 'Add Audit', 'Sync' and 'Logout' in the action bar in the home page. But none of them get displayed after running the app.

The XML content for it is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <app:item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_audit"
        android:title= "@string/add_audit"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <app:item
        android:id="@+id/action_sync"
        android:icon="@drawable/sync_outline"
        android:title="@string/action_sync"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <app:item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout_button1"
        android:title="@string/action_logout"
        app:showAsAction="withText|collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

This was working perfectly in the old project. It stopped working after I moved the content of the old project to a new one. 
I tried downgrading the compileSDKversion and targetSDKversion, but it doesn't work. 
I reviewed the code, and everything seems to be fine.

My app level gradle content is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sparsh.newcsraudit"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':squarecamera')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.16'
    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:0.9'
    implementation 'com.fabiendevos:nanotasks:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-commons:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

styles.xml has:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is the code for inflation:

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
 {
 // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
 MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();   
 inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu); 
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

I saw similar questions asked on StackOverflow but didn't get the solution.
Please help me resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add code where you inflate this menu . Or you can Follow https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html.

Comment: This is the code for inflation:

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

Comment: Edit your question .

Comment: @ADM, added that code to the question!

Comment: First thing does your `Activity` has an `ActionBar`? And I never used `<app:item>`  . Can you just replace `<app:item>`  with `<item>`.

Comment: I have used    "<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>" in styles.xml.
Please check my styles.xml in question. Setting it to true doesn't work either.